# CheckList Model Angular

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I am trying to bind CheckBoxes using CheckList Model. I am only able to get one value bound at a time and not multiple. This is based on implementation described in GitHub: http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/.

```
    <h5>Transaction Type</h5>
    <div class="filter-group">
        <div class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="picklistItem in controller.transactionTypePickList">
            <label class="filter">
                <input type="checkbox" checklist-value='picklistItem' checklist-model="controller.data.filter.TransactionTypes" />
                {{picklistItem.Value}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas why I am able to get only one value selected at a time.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: Can you create a plunker?  Or at least show your controller code?

Comment: am assuming you have a scope variable called controller that is an object holding the pat you are linking to right? in which case you are linking to a single variable if you are trying to link to a youlist  you need to use picklistItem as model

Comment: I suspect `controller.data.filter.TransactionTypes` is an array right? A plunker will be really good.